# Asserting solution existence via approximation of multi-commodity integral flow

Tags: network-flow

Consider a polynomial $\epsilon$-approximation for MCF with integral flow (like the one based on LP relaxation).

Can I (in general) use this algorithm as a predicate, asserting whether a solution exists or not?